# check if all the text box of specific type are empty

Tags: jquery, html

Hi I am a beginner in jQuery.

I want to make text boxes of specific type and want to check only on those text boxes either they are empty using jQuery.
like

```
    >>> <br/><p> pv: <input type="text" id="PVID" name="PVID" width="48" height="48"></p>
    >>> <br/><p> Date: <input type="text" name="Date"width="48" height="48"></p>
    >>> <br/><p> Reason: <input type="text" name="Reason"width="48" height="48" ></p>
    >>> <br/><p> Amount: <input type="text" name="Amount"width="48" height="48" ></p>
    >>>  5000<input type="text[0]" name="5000" >
    >>>  1000<input type="text[1]" name="1000">
    >>>  500<input type="text[2]" name="500">
    >>>  100<input type="text[3]" name="100">
```

I just want a jQuery function that returns 1 if all the `text[x]` are empty and return 0, if even a single one of it is filled.

p.s. am I correctly indexing the text boxes?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: `type="text[0]"` that's new one for me and `name="100"` not ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use name="text[]", and you gonna get an array, but as a  `type[]`   I really doubt it.

For checking the values you need  `if(!empty($_POST['PVID']))`should work for you !  Remember they are always SET either empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter your input elements based on the attribute value:

```
function allValuesEntered() {
    var return_value = true;
    $('input')
        .filter(function() {
            return $(this).attr("type").match(/text\[0-9]\]/);
        })
        .each(function() {
            if(!$(this).val()) {
                return_value = false;
            }
        });
    return return_value;
}
```

Comment: sorry for being ignorant. Its seams not to work and i cant figure out what am i going wrong :D Thankyou very much for your effort i really appriciated